# Wide character GNU libc printf

Tags: c, unicode, glibc

I am reading a file which contains both multi-byte characters and one-byte characters such as ASCII characters. I do not understand why this code does not print out the exact content of the file. Instead rubbish characters are being printed out.

The following code should merely read from the source one character at the time and
print out the file.

```
char input[] = ... <- File contents is stored there
   char * current;
   int length = strlen (input);
   current = input;
   mbstate_t state;
   memset (&state, '\0', sizeof (state));
   while (current < &input[ strlen(input) - 1])
   {
     wchar_t character;
     size_t nbytes = mbrtowc (&character, current, length, &state);
     if (nbytes == (size_t) -2 || nbytes == (size_t) -1)
     {
        fprintf (stderr, "mbrtowc returned error %ld\n", nbytes);
        return -1;
     }
     fprintf (stdout, "%ls", &character);
     current += nbytes;
     length -= nbytes;
   }
```

I don't understand what I am getting wrong, but I am sure something isn't quite right as the output is completely garbled, for instance:

`I_–_FINAN`

Results into:

```
 _

–
        _
         F
          I
           N
            A
```

Awesome!

Comment: Should `fprintf (stdout, "%ls", &character);` instead be `fprintf (stdout, "%lc", character);` ? %ls will go rummaging through whatever is in memory following `character`, expecting a string of wchar_t's until it finds a NUL.

Comment: It should be `wprintf("%lc", character);` then, shouldn't it? I think I would have used `iconv`, by the way.

Comment: Oh dear - what was I thinking that night ! If one of you can post that as an answer I can mark it with the green mark, what you see it is a fragment of the original program and iconv - of which I did not know anything, wouldn't help - but I am quite happy to know it exists as it will come handy sooner or later.